# GridX clear the sort without making new request

Tags: javascript, sorting, dojo, gridx

I am using GridX to display data, but I often change the data store that the GridX is using. I do this by using `grid.setStore()` and pass in a Dojo JsonStore (this is asynchronous data of course). I do not recreate the grid every time I change the data store, just call `setStore()`, then `refresh()`.

The grid also has the NestedSort module activated. My problem is this:

If the user sorts on a store, and then chooses a set of different data to look at, the code calls:

```
grid.sort.clear();
grid.setStore( /* new store*/ );
grid.refresh();
```

Without `.clear()` being called, **the grid will try to sort the new store** of data (which is usually invalid, and throws a 500).

With `.clear()`, the store will make a call to the server to sort the first data store, before then calling for a fresh batch of the next data store.

Ideally I want to tell the grid to clear any sort preference before I grab the next set of data, so that it is not attempting to sort it. I do not want it to make an additional call to sort the first data immediately before it gets replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I finally worked it out. To clear the sort information in the grid you must modify the grid model. The sorting in the grid model can be done using this:

```
grid.model.sort();
```